# nprogress pre-loader , dissableing my other plugin code

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am just using nprogress.js for a preloader on my page , now i have used the same code as they have in thier docs , [EXAMPLE HERE](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) .

everything works fine with this plugin ,except that i have a small issue , and that is after the plugin code is run , the rest of my code does't seem to run at all , and i have no idea why , see this [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g6fos6sc/1/)

now for testing i added a scrolll function to test my scrollbar scrolling , i have added the following code ::

```
$(window).on('scroll' , function(){
      alert('yeeeeey , we are scrolling yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey ! ');
});
```

now in the fiddle the scroll seems to fire , but in a real browser it does''t seem to fire and i don't know why . so basically the plugin nprogress is effecting my other jquery code and i have no clue why as my other code including animations and on scroll events are not fucntioning at all .

i sniff this is something obvious , but i am just not able to sniff the issue out here . can somebody tell me what i am missing .

**EDIT AND CORRECTION** ::

Ok actually the code works in a browser too , but on my live website it does't , have a look at my code below ::

```
NProgress.start();
    setTimeout(function() { NProgress.done(); $('.fade').removeClass('out'); $('#nprogress-logo').hide(); }
        , 1000);

    /*end of preloader code*/


    // $('.fade').removeClass('out'); $('#nprogress-logo').hide();

    function onScrollInit( items, trigger ) {
          items.each( function() {
            var osElement = $(this),
                osAnimationClass = osElement.attr('data-os-animation'),
                osAnimationDelay = osElement.attr('data-os-animation-delay');

            osElement.css({
                '-webkit-animation-delay':  osAnimationDelay,
                '-moz-animation-delay':     osAnimationDelay,
                'animation-delay':          osAnimationDelay
            });

            var osTrigger = ( trigger ) ? trigger : osElement;

                osTrigger.waypoint(function() {
                    osElement.addClass('animated').addClass(osAnimationClass);
                },{
                    triggerOnce: true,
                    offset: '90%'
                }); // end waypoints

          }); // end each
        }

        onScrollInit( $('.staggered-animation'), $('.staggered-animation-container') );
```

I am using waypoints to add animations , now on page load "onScrollInit" function is called , but , when i scroll to the perticular section , the animations are not added , **UNLESS** i do one of the following ::

**1.** REsize my browser , and then suddenly the animations fire ,

**2.**  The other way is wrap the code preceding the 1st setTimeout also in a setTimeout function , like so ::

```
NProgress.start();
    setTimeout(function() { NProgress.done(); $('.fade').removeClass('out'); $('#nprogress-logo').hide(); }
        , 1000);

    /*end of preloader code*/


    // $('.fade').removeClass('out'); $('#nprogress-logo').hide();

    function onScrollInit( items, trigger ) {

        console.log('inside onScrollInit');
          items.each( function() {
            var osElement = $(this),
                osAnimationClass = osElement.attr('data-os-animation'),
                osAnimationDelay = osElement.attr('data-os-animation-delay');

            osElement.css({
                '-webkit-animation-delay':  osAnimationDelay,
                '-moz-animation-delay':     osAnimationDelay,
                'animation-delay':          osAnimationDelay
            });

            var osTrigger = ( trigger ) ? trigger : osElement;

                osTrigger.waypoint(function() {
                    osElement.addClass('animated').addClass(osAnimationClass);
                },{
                    triggerOnce: true,
                    offset: '90%'
                }); // end waypoints

          }); // end each
        }


        setTimeout(function(){
            onScrollInit( $('.staggered-animation'), $('.staggered-animation-container') );
        }, 2000);
```

Notice how i have added onScrollInit to a setTimeout function ::

```
setTimeout(function(){
            onScrollInit( $('.staggered-animation'), $('.staggered-animation-container') );
        }, 2000);
```

can somebody tell me WHY is this happening ?? am i making a mistake by using setTimeout in the first place ?

Comment: gave up on pace.js huh?

Comment: It works fine in JSFiddle. Can I see what's in the real browser?

Comment: @swatkins Yeah :D :D, your answer works fine , but i already implemented nprogress :( :(  , but will surely use pace in the future , as i love the fact that it has great customizations !

Comment: @QuinnDaley yeah will show you a link , give me a few mins

Comment: @QuinnDaley sorry buddy , can't add a link , the error is difficult to re-create as a whole and i can't share the live link , i have added a elaborate explanation , can you check it out , thanks for your interest !